# How to get product specific meta data in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, metadata, product

I'm using WooCommerce and want to get the meta keys specifically for the product e.g. price, color and so on...
But the problem is that I don't want to get all meta keys but only the ones needed. For example I don't need `_edit_last`, `_edit_lock`, `_wc_review_count` ... and just need `price` and `color` (as an example). If it was a web page that wasn't important but I don't want to show them on web page but I want to send them as json to somewhere else. So the data should be filtered. BTW it is in plugin and I want to share it with others so I can't/shouldn't access their WooCommerce api.

my code that gets all meta keys (but I want only some of them):

```
$attributes = get_post_meta($product->get_id());
foreach($attributes as $key => $value) {
    $result['products'][$p]['attributes'][$key] = $value[0];
}
```

and the result of code above is:

```
[attributes] => Array
(
    [_edit_last] => 1
    [_edit_lock] => 1594817821:1
    .
    .
    .
)
```

but I want:

```
[attributes] => Array
(
    [price] => 1000
    [color] => 'red'
    .
    .
    .
)
```

Answer (score 10):

There is multiple ways depending on what you want:

1). You will need to use [`WC_Product` methods](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product.html) on the WC_Product Object to get product properties:

```
$product_id = 37; // Defined product Id for testing

// Get the WC_Product Object from the product ID (optional)
$product = wc_get_product($product_id); // If needed

// Get product active price
$product_data = $product->get_price();

// … and so on …
```

2). For specific or custom product meta data, you will use [`WC_Data` method `get_meta()`](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/classes/WC-Data.html#method_get_meta) using the desired meta key like:

```
$product_id = 37; // Defined product Id for testing

// Get the WC_Product Object from the product ID (optional)
$product = wc_get_product($product_id); // If needed

// Get custom meta data froma specific meta key
$product_data = $product->get_meta('my_meta_key');

// … and so on …
```

3). You can use instead the [`WC_Data` method `get_data()`](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/classes/WC-Data.html#method_get_data) on the `WC_Product` object to get unprotected meta data in an array:

```
$product_id = 37; // Defined product Id for testing

// Get the WC_Product Object from the product ID (optional)
$product = wc_get_product($product_id); // If needed

// Get product unprotected meta data in an array
$product_data = $product->get_data();

// Output row data
echo '<pre>'. print_r( $obj, true ) . '</pre>';
```

You will get something like (extract):

```
Array
(
    [id] => 37
    [name] => Happy Ninja Dish Hip
    [slug] => happy-ninja-dish
    [date_created] => WC_DateTime Object
        (
            [utc_offset:protected] => 0
            [date] => 2015-12-26 11:53:15.000000
            [timezone_type] => 3
            [timezone] => Europe/Paris
        )

    [date_modified] => WC_DateTime Object
        (
            [utc_offset:protected] => 0
            [date] => 2020-07-09 19:25:32.000000
            [timezone_type] => 3
            [timezone] => Europe/Paris
        )

    [status] => publish
    [featured] => 
    [catalog_visibility] => visible
    [description] => Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet…

[add_to_cart id="53"]
    [short_description] => Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus...
    [sku] => Gh2563
    [price] => 90.50
    [regular_price] => 100
    [sale_price] => 90.50

// … and so on …
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is [Woocommerce Code Reference](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/classes/WC-Data.html#method_get_meta) about how to get metadata from each product.

Also, this is example how to get metadata by key below:

```
function woo_custom_additional_information_tab_content() {

global $product;

$product_data = $product->get_meta('_specifications');

echo $product_data;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

There can be two ways to do this, One is to filter the metadata array manually in the foreach loop and other is to hit a custom query to wp_postmeta table for specific keys.